# How create a dynamic layer in OpenLayers map

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wms

I am using GeoServer, PostGIS (database) and OpenLayers for map. Now I want to create a layer (WFS, WMS) dynamically. The goal is to allow the user to create any number of layers from front end without hard coding in (map.js) file.

Is it possible?

Comment: You need to provide more details:What input will the user give? How will the user provide this Input? What have you done so far? What kind of error checking will you do? What base layers do you have in the map by default?

Comment: Your question does not make sense, you must have some kind of predetermined list of what layers are actually available on GeoServer. Users just cannot create layers from nothing. Please be more specific about the number of layers you have on GeoServer, what the expected user interaction is, ie: will they choose from a list, and whether the layers on Geoserver are Static, or are being added to all the time. (Plus what Devdatta Tengshe suggested you provide as well.)